# Immutables wrapper as string in Jackson

Tags: jackson, immutables-library

How can I jackson serialize a wrapper type to and from a string?

I merged the following from two different examples their website. But the HostName type is serialized/deserialized as

```
{ "name" : "my.host.name.com" }
```

when I want it to be simply the string

```
"my.host.name.com"
```

Note that I have a *lot* of XName types, hence the use of the Immutables wrapper. So I would prefer a solution that keeps the amount of boiler plate down.

---

```
@Value.Immutable @AbstractName.Wrapper
public abstract class _HostName extends AbstractName { }

...

public abstract class AbstractName {

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonDeserialize
    @Value.Style(
        // Detect names starting with underscore
        typeAbstract = "_*",
        // Generate without any suffix, just raw detected name
        typeImmutable = "*",
        // Make generated public, leave underscored as package private
        visibility = Value.Style.ImplementationVisibility.PUBLIC,
        // Seems unnecessary to have builder or superfluous copy method
        defaults = @Value.Immutable(builder = false, copy = false))
    public @interface Wrapper {}




    @Value.Parameter
    public abstract String name();

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this to work like below. There's an extra annotation on my name types. It's not my favorite, but it works.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=HostName.class)
@Value.Immutable @AbstractName.Wrapper
public abstract class _HostName extends AbstractName { }

...

public abstract class AbstractName {

    @Value.Style(
        // Detect names starting with underscore
        typeAbstract = "_*",
        // Generate without any suffix, just raw detected name
        typeImmutable = "*",
        // Make generated public, leave underscored as package private
        visibility = Value.Style.ImplementationVisibility.PUBLIC,
        // Seems unnecessary to have builder or superfluous copy method
        defaults = @Value.Immutable(builder = false, copy = false))
    public @interface Wrapper {}


    @JsonValue
    @Value.Parameter
    public abstract String name();

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name(); }
}
```

Here's a little program to run it:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();

    String text = json.writeValueAsString(HostName.of("my.host.name.com"));

    System.out.println(text);

    HostName hostName = json.readValue(text, HostName.class);
    System.out.println(hostName);
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this, my own answer, for now. If someone has something better, I'm more than happy to give the accept to them.